# Sharepoint: How to connect to a web service (MOSS Server not on a Domain)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss

In a typical (professional) environment you would expect MOSS to reside on a domain

so this code is used to create the credentials to a web service method :

```
dwsService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Tanveer", "Test", "MyDomain");
```

Anyone have any experience when MOSS does not reside on a domain? How then can you pass a local admin account through to the credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkCredential has a second contructor without a domain parameter:

```
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
```

Also, you can provide the server name as the domain parameter:

```
NetworkCredential secondNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "serverName");
```